# How to bound a function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to prove that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that

$$e^{\Big(tanh(\frac{t}{2})-\frac{t}{2}\Big)b^2}\le e^{-ct^3b^2}$$ for all $b\in\mathbb{R}$ and for all $t\le 1$.

Please help me to do so. Thanks

Comment: Where does $\nu$ appear?

Comment: sorry there is no $\nu$

Comment: that is equivalent to show that $ct^3\le \frac{t}{2}-\tanh(\frac{t}{2})$ or $\tanh(\frac{t}{2})\le  \frac{t}{2}-ct^3$

Answer (score 0):

The exponential function is monotonically increasing, so you want $c$ such that 
$$ \left( \tanh(t/2) - t/2 \right) b^2 \leq -c t^3 b^2  \text{.}  $$
Since $b$ is real, either $b = 0$, giving equality in the above, or $b^2 > 0$ and we can divide it from both sides, giving 
$$ \tanh(t/2) - t/2 \leq -c t^3  \text{.}  $$
Recall the power series for $\tanh(t/2) = \frac{t}{2} - \frac{t^3}{24} + \frac{t^5}{240} - \frac{17t^7}{40320} + \cdots$, so
$$ \tanh(t/2) - t/2 \in \left( \frac{-t^3}{24}, \frac{-t^3}{24} + \frac{t^5}{240} \right)$$ for all $t$ in the radius of convergence.  So take $c = 1/24$, since 
$$ \tanh(t/2) - t/2 \leq -\frac{1}{24} t^3 $$ within that radius.  The radius of convergence is $|t| < \pi$, so the above resolves the question for $t \in (-\pi, 1]$.

At $t = -\pi$, $\tanh(-\pi/2)- \frac{-\pi}{2} = 0.65364\dots{} < 1.2919\dots{} = \frac{-1}{24}(-\pi)^3$.  For $t < -\pi$, we have $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \tanh(t/2) - t/2 = -1/2 + \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{sech}^2(t/2) > -1/2$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{-t^3}{24} < \frac{-\pi^2}{8}< -1$, so the ordering of the two expressions at $t = -\pi$ does not reverse anywhere to the left of $-\pi$.  That is, the inequality holds on $(-\infty, -\pi]$ as well.

(Note:  There are many ways to show what is essentially a line, $\tanh(t/2) - t/2 < -t/2$ is less than the cubic, $-c t^3$, on $(-\infty, \pi]$.  I've just picked a relatively elementary method above: the cubic is always descending faster than $\tanh(t/2) - t/2$ and they have not crossed by $t= -\pi$.)

Comment: Thanks Eric, can us show that $tanh(t/2)-t/2\le -ct/2$ for all $t>1$?

Comment: Yes.  Easiest is to look at $\frac{\tanh(t/2) - t/2}{-t/2}$ on $(1,\infty)$, observe that it is monotonically increasing and so lower bounded by $1 - 2 \tanh(1/2) = 0.0757\dots{} < 1/24 = c$, so the same $c$ works.